# Probability of return with 7% error

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a problem understanding the answer of the following problem:

> A recent audit by the IRS of the returns she prepared indicated that
>   an error was made on 7% of the returns she prepared last year.
>   Assuming this rate continues into this years and she prepares 80
>   returns. What is the probability that she makes:

a) More than 6 returns.
First i calculate μ: (80)0.07 =5.6 
Q1:From the 5.6 I dont understand how you get to the variance of 5.208
the standard deviation 2.2821 is used in the next formula:
z=(6.5-5.6)/2.2821 = 0.39

Q2: Why do we have xi as 6.5? What is the rational behind that for more than 6 returns?
When i want to find the value for at least 6 returns i am supposed to do μ - xi

Q3: In the first case the corresponding area is 0.1517- 0.1517= 0.3483 
I dont understand how to get these numbers.

Thank you for any help i can get with understanding this.

Comment: Hello, xtrasy, and welcome to Math.SE. I tried to edit your question, making notations clearer, but I realized there's some things in your question that you'd most probably would like to solve by yourself, like in question 2, clarifying what *xi* is supposed to mean, or in Q3, that '-'. Note that you can use LATEX commands between $'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a binomial model of the number of errors. For a binomial distribution for errors with $N$ cases and an error rate probability $p$ the mean number of errors is $\mu=Np$ and the standard deviation of the number of errors is $\sigma=\sqrt{Np(1-p)}$. Plugging in $N=80$ and $p=0.07$ (which is 7%)  gives $\mu=5.6$ and $\sigma=2.2821$.

For the second question you now seem to be using the normal approximation to the binomial distribution. The normal distribution is continuous and the binomial discrete, so we need to apply a continuity correction, so more than $6$ errors for the binomial model becomes more than $6.5$ for the normal approximation.

The $z$ score corresponding to $6.5$ errors in the normal model is 
$$
z=\frac{6.5-\mu}{\sigma}=\frac{6.5-5.6}{2.2821}=0.39437
$$
We look up this z-score in a table of the cumulative standard normal function and find the probability of **less** than $6.5$ errors is $0.65335$ and so the probability of more is $1-0.65335=0.34665$.

Comment: +1 though I think that $1-\Phi(0.39437) \approx 0.3467$ rather than $0.34827$.  It is worth noting this is only an approximation, and using the binomial distribution would give about $0.3273$.

Comment: @Henry, Thanks for spotting what was a typing glitch in octave, and yes I also would use the binomial distribution if it were up to me but the question implies that the normal approximation is in play here.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great explanation Conrad, it clarified quite a lot for me.